# filter image with opencv

Tags: qt, opencv

I have an image which I would like to extract the number but in a dynamic way (I don't want to specify a roi because image may vary) so I have to filter it. I tried to detect the horizontal line(to crop the image) but it failed. I would like to detect high density zones in the binary image (the face and the top of the image)

ps:my problem isn't how to extract numbers but to specify the roi
and all the images have the same format
any help would be appreciated(even without code just the big lines)

thanks

the image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would start form  detecting frame of the whole document.
If you google: [rectangle detection opencv](http://www.google.pl/search?q=rectangle%20detection%20opencv), you will find lots of examples.
In second stage i would apply [inRange](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=inrange#inrange) to filter purple line and detect it with [HoughLines](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html#houghlines). 
This should be enough to calculate ROI.